# Degree of quaternion product composed with two maps of $S^3$

Tags: homology-cohomology, quaternions

> Let $S^3$ denote the unit quaternions with multiplication $\mu:S^3\times S^3\rightarrow S^3$.Show that if $f_1,f_2:S^3\rightarrow S^3$ are given maps,that the composition $$S^3\xrightarrow{f_1\times f_2}S^3\times S^3\xrightarrow{\mu}S^3$$ has degree equal to $deg(f_1)+deg(f_2)$, i.e. $$deg(\mu(f_1,f_2))=deg(f_1)+deg(f_2)$$

My confusion is that I cannot calculate the degree by composion since the middle one is not a sphere and the quaternion multiplication is also a bit of complex to deal with.How to deal with that?Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm really rusty on this and never really worked with cohomology rings. Yet I get this feeling that something like the following could be the key. The third homology of $S^3\times S^3$ is in some sense generated by cells of the form $S^3\times \{*\}$ and $\{*\}\times S^3$. But the restriction of $\mu$ to either of those is a homeomorphism to $S^3$. Really, if $*$ is the neutral element, it is the identity mapping. Pulling all this back et cetera suggests to me that at the level of cohomology rings the generator of $H^3(S^3)$ maps to the sum of the two generators of $H^3(S^3\times S^3)$ and..

Comment: Why do you use cohomology to calculate the degree?In Hatcher I just find it calculated in homology.I feel that the trouble in this problem is that the relation between $(f_1,f_2)_\star$ and $({f_1}_\star,{f_2}_\star)$ is not so clear except for the projection property.