# representation for elements in $\pi_3(S^3)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, quaternions

I want to know if the map between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_3(S^3) $ given by $a \mapsto (x \mapsto x^a)$, where $S^3$ is seen as a subset of $\mathbb{H}$ with its multiplication, gives an isomorphism just like the case $\pi_1(S^1) $?

Comment: Interesting question. It would all come down to computing the degree of the map $x \mapsto x^a$. Have you attempted that?

Comment: My gut guess is no, since the proof of the case for $S^1$ through covers relies on the commutativity in the cover.  However, I have no real reason for this.  [There is also a point in the argument where you need the induced map from $\pi_1(S^1)$ to the fiber $\mathbb{Z}$ to be a homomorphism, but here the map $x \mapsto x^a$ is not a group homomorphism.]  Good question.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1740250/221315

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes: Since quaternionic multiplication equips $S^3$ with an H-space structure, the sets $[X, S^3]_*$ inherit a multiplication (which we denote by $\mathbin{\cdot_{\mathbb{H}}}$) for all $X$, and specializing to $X = S^n$ this agrees with the usual multiplication on homotopy groups. Now $[\mathrm{id}_{S^3}]$ is a generator for $\pi_3(S^3)$ and $\mathrm{id}_{S^3} \mathbin{\cdot_{\mathbb{H}}} \mathrm{id}_{S^3} = (x \mapsto x \cdot x = x^2)$, whence $\mathrm{id}_{S^3}^n = (x \mapsto x^n)$ represents $n \cdot [\mathrm{id}_{S^3}]$ in $\pi_3(S^3)$ and your map is an isomorphism.

Comment: $S^3$ is actually a Lie group, of course. But why does the induced multiplication on $[S^3,S^3]_*$ agree with the usual multiplication on homotopy groups?

Comment: @LeeMosher Prove that the two multiplications satisfy interchange and apply the Eckman-Hilton argument. For reference, this is exercise 4.1.3 in Hatcher.